# Creating a parent-child data entry form in access

Tags: database, forms, ms-access, parent-child

I have created a form that requires the following inputs "Master Label", "Child Label(s)" which has a submit button to enter the record. Is there a way to keep the "Master Label" field the same and allow multiple submissions of different child labels.

Then when I am ready for a new Master label I will simply insert a button "New Master Label" that will clear out the previous Master Label.

Comment: Yes? It's fairly confusing what you're trying to explain here though. How're you controlling the form in question, is that through VBA? Also what're the methods for the "inputs" you mentioned?

Comment: The form is controlled by VBA, the on click event for the submit button updates the underlying table with the data that was entered.  What I am trying to accomplish is to leave the Master Label unchanged until the user decides its time to change it rather than having to repeatedly scan the same label every time that a new child label for that master label is being recorded.

Comment: Would you kindly `post your code` for the proces in question?

Comment: Question makes me suspect database design is not optimized for relational principles. Why would Master/Child properties need to be dynamic in a form/subform arrangement?

Comment: Use a form/subform construction.

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out.

```
Private Sub Child_Label_Input_Exit(Cancel As Integer)
With CodeContextObject
Me.Parent_Label.DefaultValue = """" & Me.Parent_Label & """"
End With
End Sub
```